# insert into database mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to upload an image to my server and save its name and path into my database. Uploading the file to my server works, saving the data in the database does not.
**images table**

```
image_id    int(11)      
image_name  varchar(64)          
image_path  varchar(64)
```

**Upload script**

```
    // Upload image to the server
    $target_dir = "./path/to/image/folder/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "Die Datei ist keine Bilddatei.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Bitte nenne die Datei um, diese Datei existiert bereits.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Diese Datei ist größer als 5MB und kann daher nicht hochgeladen werden.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Ausschließlich JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF Dateien können hochgeladen werden.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Die Datei konnte nicht hochgeladen werden.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        ========================= DATABASE PART ========================
        // create a database connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        // prepare and bind
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image_id, image_name, image_path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("iss", $image_id, $image_name, $image_path);

        // set parameters and execute
        $image_id = '';
        $image_name = $target_file;
        $image_path = $target_dir;
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
        ==================================================================

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {            
            header("Location:http://homepage.com");
        } else {
            echo "Während des Hochladens der Bilddatei ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuche es erneut.";
        }
    }
```

**The file is uploaded exactly as it should be.**
**The database stays empty without an error message.**
**var_dump on `$image_name` and `$image_path` return the correct values.**
What am I missing?
I would be very thankful for any kind of help. Thank you!

Comment: no error handling on the connection, prepare, bind or execute. there is no way to know what went wrong

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: seems you're putting the wagon before the horse here and you should be getting notices about it.

Comment: more like `off the wagon`

Comment: @amdixon Just in time for New Year's. No better time to be "off the wagon" for a while ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- very true, happy new year. may the errors be with you ;)

Comment: Great! Thank you! Then I will do more error handling. I thought probably an experienced eye could spot my mistake right away. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @amdixon *Cheers to you too!* grazie

Comment: *"I thought probably an experienced eye could spot my mistake right away."* - haven't we?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: @Fred-ii- that is true! :)

Comment: I like making a person "think" as that translates to *"Teach a person how to fish, feed them for life"* ;-) @kringeltorte

Comment: so... this still isn't solved I see. I have my doubts as to why it's failing. but that guy below got an upvote and he's not responding yet in regards to the new error you got. Unless........... he's busy trying to find how "why".

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think he gave up... But the error handling already helped me a lot! At least I have something to work with now! By now I get the file_exists() error, which is very weird but at least I am getting error messages! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: the error comes most likely from `$image_id = '';` since nothing is assigned to it, and I am assuming that that column is an AI? (that could have a bearing on all this) what would you like to do with the question here? I didn't post an answer probably due to my instincts on this one. If the guy can't resolve it and you happen to (at some point), then you can post your own answer. But, I'm betting my money on that first parameter. Replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` if you're not already doing so.

Comment: addendum to above. change `INSERT INTO images (image_id, image_name, image_path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)` to `INSERT INTO images ('', image_name, image_path) VALUES (?, ?)` and remove the bind `bind_param("ss", $image_name, $image_path)` if that column is an AI. or something similar. I think you get the gist of it. Or assign something to it `$image_id = '123';`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you so much for all your help! I took away the image_id and at least now there is something arriving in my database! :) However, that is something very very weird! The image pth looks like this: `imgs/impressionen/image.jpg./imgs/impressionen` it is supposed to be `./imgs/impressionen/image.jpg`. '

Comment: you're welcome. now that answer got another upvote without even doing anything for it. sorry, but I've put in enough time already that led to more success than what that guy has done. all the best, I gotta run. my espresso machine's ready. *ciao!* e buon anno!!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
// prepare and bind
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image_id, image_name, image_path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("iss", $image_id, $image_name, $image_path);

        // set parameters and execute
        $image_id = '';
        $image_name = $target_file;
        $image_path = $target_dir;
        $stmt->execute();
```

Try:

```
// set parameters and execute
$image_id = '';
$image_name = $target_file;
$image_path = $target_dir;

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image_id, image_name, image_path) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iss", $image_id, $image_name, $image_path);
```

The order of code execution is from top to bottom.
Right now you call variables while you haven't set them.

Comment: which [what I said here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547611/insert-into-database-mysqli-prepared-statement#comment56836926_34547611) translates to that. [You're just saying "Try".](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34547688/1) Edit: [you edited.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34547688/revisions)

Comment: @SuperDJ Thank you for your answer! Now, at least I get an error message, I can work on (Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object).